# end of year date formula - salesforce

Tags: datetime, salesforce, formula, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have start and end dates on my salesforce opportunities and I am creating a formula to divide opportunity revenue across the number of months.

What I want to do is as explained below....

For Example:

Start Date = 01/05/2022

End Date = 10/04/2023

I created a field formula to show how many months are between these dates like this:

```
((CloseDate - Estimated_Start_Date__c) /(365/12))
```

and I can then divide my revenue by the number of months shown.

**BUT** what I want to do is ideally the same as above but show only the amount of months between my start date and the end of the year (31/12/2022)

The result being I can show my revenue split for the whole opportunity and also just for 2022.

Can anyone advise on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the below formula

```
MONTH(CloseDate) - MONTH(Estimated_Start_Date__c)
```